# Import xml inside wordpress and automaticly add positions to each page's google maps

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, google-maps

So administrator should be able to login and upload an xml from backend.
When uploaded WordPress it self would then add each of the cordinates to right page's google maps.

Example of xml file. 
First goes city name/wordpress page name and then cordinates for that place in that city.
Amsterdam - 52.372620, 4.820508 
Barcelona - 41.403224, 2.174260

So my two questions are
1. Is there any plugins to make this job easier
2. How would you do this ?

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources (like wordpress plugs) are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Alright. Ignore my first question...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iframe API. All you need to do in your Wordpress PHP is to add

```
    <iframe
       width="600"
       height="450"
       frameborder="0" style="border:0"
       src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q="+YOUR_LAT_LNG allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

onto your page. You will also need to apply for an API key in the  Google Developers Console. Check here for instruction https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#api_key